# Parsing a same tag with same class in BS4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hello to all of you

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as b


data = """
<div class="hello1">
<span class="string1">This is string 1</span>
<span class="string2">This is string 2</span>
</div>
<div class="hello2">
<span class="string1">Another String 1</span>
</div>"""

bsObj = b(data, 'html.parser')
print(bsObj.find('span', 'string'))
```

Now I want to parse the "Another String 1" only but when I'm run the code, The result is "This is string 1".
If I change the find into findAll it prints string1 from div.hello1 and div.hello2 but I only want is the span in div.hello2

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell BS *where* you want to search for the span:

```
bsObj.find('div','hello2').find('span','string1')
#<span class="string1">Another String 1</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS selector to target your tags with methods `select()`/`select_one()`. Selector `div.hello2 span` will target `<span>` tag under `<div>` tag with class `hello2`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as b

data = """
<div class="hello1">
<span class="string1">This is string 1</span>
<span class="string2">This is string 2</span>
</div>
<div class="hello2">
<span class="string1">Another String 1</span>
</div>"""

bsObj = b(data, 'html.parser')

print(bsObj.select_one('div.hello2 span').text)
```

Prints:

```
Another String 1
```